# Does there exist a non-linear version of Fourier Transforms?

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

So I just completed an undergraduate course on PDEs, and one of the ways(my personal favorite from the course) to solve a PDE is using Fourier Transforms. Fourier Transforms are linear transformations, but out of curiosity does there a exist a non-linear version or generalization of Fourier Transforms? Where this thought comes from is that I have worked with Euclidean Transformations which are linear until you generalize it to include translations at which point it becomes an affine(and therefore non-linear) transformation. I am curious to know if there was something similar for Fourier Transforms.

Comment: It's still linear but you may be interested in the Radon transform: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform

Comment: You may be interested in oscillatory integrals : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillatory_integral

Comment: Thank you both! I'll read more about them